# Problem with calculutor, calculus

Tags: babel, languages, calculations

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{calculator} % 2014/02/20 v.2.0
\usepackage{calculus}   % 2014/02/20 v.2.0

\begin{document}

Ş ş Ç ç % Before

\newcommand\gga{10}
\newcommand\ggb{30}
\newcommand\ggc{5}
\newcommand\ggd{5}
\newcommand\gge{10}
\newcommand\ggf{9}

\ADD{\gga}{\ggb}\a
\ADD{\ggc}{\ggd}\b
%\ADD{\gge}{\ggf}\c %<----- This Line

Ş ş Ç ç % After

\end{document}
```

and output,

[image]

no problem. But added the **This Line**,

[image]

How is it changing macro in MWE?

Comment: Don't use single letters like this: many are already defined to mark accents (e.g., `\b`, `\c`, `\d`, `\H`, `\k`, `\r`, `\t`, `\u`, `\v`).

Comment: A colleague of mine had an issue with a paper; I discovered that he was redefining `\c` (to `\gamma`, because he knew Greek), but that particular paper had a Turkish coauthor whose surname started with `Ş`. Don't use `\def` unless you have a good reason to; packages such as `calculator` that do redefinitions without any check are to be avoided, in my opinion. Use some distinguishable prefix, like you did at the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{calculator} % 2014/02/20 v.2.0
\usepackage{calculus}   % 2014/02/20 v.2.0

\begin{document}

Ş ş Ç ç % Before

\newcommand\gga{10}
\newcommand\ggb{30}
\newcommand\ggc{5}
\newcommand\ggd{5}
\newcommand\gge{10}
\newcommand\ggf{9}

\ADD{\gga}{\ggb}\sola
\ADD{\ggc}{\ggd}\solb
\ADD{\gge}{\ggf}\solc %<----- This Line

\show\c  \show\solc  % Look into the log file

Ş ş Ç ç % After

\end{document}
```

It seems that your used macro `\c` has another definition and gives the problem.  Follow the documentation and use varaiables `\solx` for your solutions. Change `x` to what you need, for example `c`.

With `\show` you can see in the log file, what the following macro means. The result for my MWE is:

```
> \c=macro:
->\T1-cmd \c \T1\c .
l.25 \show\c
              \show\solc

> \solc=macro:
->19.
```

You see, macro `\solc` has the value 19.

Result in your pdf:

[image]

At last the reason for this behaviour is that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` translates Ş into `\c{S}` (and similarly for the other letters with the cedilla). `\c` marks the "cedillia" that is added to the following letter (here in the example `S`).  Now you redefined the cedillia to `19` so you get at last `\c{S}` --> `19{S}` --> `19S`. And so redefining \c is definitely a bad idea, especially for Turks (Thanks to @egreg for his great comment!)

Comment: Oh my God. I don't believe that. :).

Comment: @Özgür In LaTeX exists a lot of predefined macros. `\c` marks the accent you used in your text line. Thats the reason you got 19 (new content of `\c`) followed by S etc.  (Sorry, I do not know the english name of this accent)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the under accent is called “Çengel işareti” or “Sedil” in Turkish and “cedilla” in English. “Cedille" in German. You could add that the `utf8` option to `inputenc` translates `Ş` into `\c{S}` (and similarly for the other letters with the cedilla), so redefining `\c` is definitely a bad idea, especially for Turks.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I added your comment to my answer. I hope that is okay for you?!